# how to merge (group) rows belonging to the same session

Tags: postgresql, group-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

A visitor can `OPEN` the front door of a house and then `ENTER` several rooms in the house. After all this, he will `OPEN` the front door again, to leave house. This gives the following example data:

```
13:00 John  OPEN
13:00 John  ENTER Hall
13:30 John  ENTER Kitchen
13:45 John  ENTER Living room
14:00 John  OPEN
13:30 Steve OPEN
13:30 Steve ENTER Hall
13:40 Steve ENTER Stairs
14:00 Steve ENTER Bed room
16:00 Steve ENTER Stairs
16:10 Steve OPEN
```

So in other words, we always have one single `OPEN` entry, then one or more `ENTER` entries, to end with one single `OPEN` entry. Also, multiple visitors can be in the house at the same time and they can visit the house multiple times, there are no restrictions at all.

Let's define a sequence from `OPEN` to `OPEN` as a session. I now want to create a single row for each session containing all the happened events as following:

```
[13:00,14:00) John  (13:00,Hall),(13:30,Kitchen),(13:45,Living room)
[13:30,16:10) Steve (13:30,Hall),(13:40,Stairs),(14:00,Bed room),(16:00,Stairs)
```

How can this be done efficiently?

I have a working `n^2` solution which first fetches the first and last `ENTER` for each session (with window functions `lead` and `lag` and then comparing with the previous one), and then searches in an outer loop for all interleaving `ENTER` entries. This obviously does not perform well.

Is there a way to scan once through the data set, mark all `ENTER` entries belonging to the same session a unique sequence number, and then finally group on that sequence? I am breaking my head over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to `SUM` the occurrences of `OPEN` up to the current row in the table (partitioned by name and sorted by time), and divide that by 2 to get the current access number. This can then be used to group results:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *,
         (1 + SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time)) / 2 AS access
  FROM data
)
SELECT MIN(time), MAX(time), name, ARRAY_AGG(time || ',' || action) AS actions
FROM CTE
GROUP BY name, access
ORDER BY MIN(time), name
```

Output (of my expanded demo with a second access by `John`):

```
min     max     name    actions
13:00   14:00   John    ["13:00,OPEN","13:00,ENTER Hall","13:30,ENTER Kitchen","13:45,ENTER Living room","14:00,OPEN"]
13:30   16:10   Steve   ["13:30,OPEN","13:30,ENTER Hall","13:40,ENTER Stairs","14:00,ENTER Bed room","16:00,ENTER Stairs","16:10,OPEN"]
15:00   16:00   John    ["15:00,OPEN","15:00,ENTER Hall","15:30,ENTER Kitchen","15:45,ENTER Living room","16:00,OPEN"]
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tpxzqgCbYRYg2wP29zKX2U/0)